# Moving image imageview

Tags: android, image, move

I have a question. I've done in XML ImageView. Unfortunately, the "holds" on the left side of the screen on the phone. I wish this picture could shift to the right place.
I would like to point to the X and Y position of the image shifted to the indicated place.
How do I do this?
Please explain in detail because I am a novice programmer of Java.
Sorry for the mistakes. I'm not saying every day in the English language.

Answer (score 1):

I'd not recommend setting fixed positions for elements as it will make your life only harder for different screen sizes.

Use a `RelativeLayout`. Here is an example of how your XML could look like.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <ImageView 
   android:id="@+id/imageview"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:src="@drawable/icon"
   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This way the `ImageView` will always be bound to its parents right side. This is achieved by setting `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` on the `ImageView`.

Hope it helps.